# tf2 tutorial writing broadcaster -- compile error

Tags: ros, tf2-ros, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm following the tutorial at http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29

I copy-and-pasted the code, made changes to CMakeLists.txt, but I see this error when I `catkin_make`:

```
CMakeFiles/turtle_tf2_broadcaster.dir/src/turtle_tf2_broadcaster.cpp.o: In function `poseCallback(boost::shared_ptr<turtlesim::Pose_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)':
turtle_tf2_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster::TransformBroadcaster()'
turtle_tf2_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x1d3): undefined reference to `tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster::sendTransform(geometry_msgs::TransformStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm fairly sure I've followed each step correctly (and the Python version works for me). I checked `/opt/ros/hydro/include/tf2_ros/transform_broadcaster.h` and `sendTransform()` seems to be defined:

```
  /** \brief Send a TransformStamped message
   * The stamped data structure includes frame_id, and time, and parent_id already.  */
  void sendTransform(const geometry_msgs::TransformStamped & transform);

  /** \brief Send a vector of TransformStamped messages
   * The stamped data structure includes frame_id, and time, and parent_id already.  */
  void sendTransform(const std::vector<geometry_msgs::TransformStamped> & transforms);
```

Is there something else with the C++ version that I'm overlooking?

I'm using Hydro with 12.04.5.

Thanks!

---

**EDIT with CMakeLists.txt and compile output:**

CMakeList.txt:

```
make_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(learning_tf2)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  tf2
  turtlesim
)

## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES learning_tf2
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy tf2 turtlesim
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

install(PROGRAMS
  nodes/turtle_tf2_broadcaster.py
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(FILES
  start_demo.launch
  # myfile2
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)

add_executable(turtle_tf2_broadcaster src/turtle_tf2_broadcaster.cpp)
target_link_libraries(turtle_tf2_broadcaster ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

catkin_make output:

```
$ catkin_make VERBOSE=1
Base path: /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/install" in "/home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/local/nitekrawler/adn/AdnSensors/rigs/handheld-backyard-rig/devel;/home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/hydro
-- This workspace overlays: /home/local/nitekrawler/adn/AdnSensors/rigs/handheld-backyard-rig/devel;/home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/hydro
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Python version: 2.7
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.90
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 3 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - imu_test
-- ~~  - learning_tf
-- ~~  - learning_tf2
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'imu_test'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(imu_test)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'learning_tf'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(learning_tf)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'learning_tf2'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(learning_tf2)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build
####
#### Running command: "make VERBOSE=1 -j4 -l4" in "/home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build"
####
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/src -B/home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build'
make -f imu_test/CMakeFiles/imu_test.dir/build.make imu_test/CMakeFiles/imu_test.dir/depend
make -f learning_tf2/CMakeFiles/turtle_tf2_broadcaster.dir/build.make learning_tf2/CMakeFiles/turtle_tf2_broadcaster.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build'
cd /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/src /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/src/imu_test /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build/imu_test /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build/imu_test/CMakeFiles/imu_test.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build'
cd /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/src /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/src/learning_tf2 /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build/learning_tf2 /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build/learning_tf2/CMakeFiles/turtle_tf2_broadcaster.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build'
make -f learning_tf2/CMakeFiles/turtle_tf2_broadcaster.dir/build.make learning_tf2/CMakeFiles/turtle_tf2_broadcaster.dir/build
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build'
make -f imu_test/CMakeFiles/imu_test.dir/build.make imu_test/CMakeFiles/imu_test.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `imu_test/CMakeFiles/imu_test.dir/build'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles  4
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build'
[ 50%] Built target imu_test
Linking CXX executable /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/devel/lib/learning_tf2/turtle_tf2_broadcaster
cd /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build/learning_tf2 && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/turtle_tf2_broadcaster.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++       CMakeFiles/turtle_tf2_broadcaster.dir/src/turtle_tf2_broadcaster.cpp.o  -o /home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/devel/lib/learning_tf2/turtle_tf2_broadcaster -rdynamic /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp.so -lboost_signals-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt /opt/ros/hydro/lib/librosconsole.so /opt/ros/hydro/lib/librosconsole_log4cxx.so /opt/ros/hydro/lib/librosconsole_backend_interface.so -llog4cxx -lboost_regex-mt /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libxmlrpcpp.so /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libtf2.so /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp_serialization.so /opt/ros/hydro/lib/librostime.so -lboost_date_time-mt -lboost_system-mt -lboost_thread-mt -lpthread /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libcpp_common.so /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libconsole_bridge.so -Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/hydro/lib 
CMakeFiles/turtle_tf2_broadcaster.dir/src/turtle_tf2_broadcaster.cpp.o: In function `poseCallback(boost::shared_ptr<turtlesim::Pose_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)':
turtle_tf2_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster::TransformBroadcaster()'
turtle_tf2_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x1d3): undefined reference to `tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster::sendTransform(geometry_msgs::TransformStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/devel/lib/learning_tf2/turtle_tf2_broadcaster] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build'
make[1]: *** [learning_tf2/CMakeFiles/turtle_tf2_broadcaster.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/local/nitekrawler/catkin_ws/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211596/tf2-tutorial-writing-broadcaster----compile-error/) by [nitekrawler](https://answers.ros.org/users/20470/nitekrawler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2015-06-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-06-17**:
Please post your CMakeLists.txt contents, as well as your full console output of the compile. (VERBOSE=1 will give you more info as well.)

It looks like you're missing some link flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the missing symbol it looks like you need add tf2_ros to your `find_package(catkin`... list

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [votecoffee](https://answers.ros.org/users/58616/votecoffee/) on 2020-09-21**:
That fixed my issue as well.  Thanks!